# Worklight - SOAP adapter unable to parse <soapenv:Envelope> request

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to create a **SOAP adapter** which uses **soapenv:Envelope** request. But when I invoke the adapter eclipse produces following error - 
      {
      "errors": [
      "Ecma Error: **TypeError: Cannot read property \"Body\"** from undefined 
     (C%3A%5Cdevelopment%5Cmywork%5CWorklight%5CWorklightApp
      lications%5Cadapters%5CSOAPAdapter/SOAPAdapter-impl.js#40)"
     ],
    "info": [
    ],
    "isSuccessful": false,
    "warnings": [
    ] 
     }

It seems to be a SAXParser issue therefore I googled it and got a solution from IBM developers forum **(http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=454988)** - 
After the -vmargs line in eclipse.ini, add this
line and then restart Eclipse:
**-Dorg.xml.sax.driver=com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.SAXParser**

I did that but still I am getting the same error. Here is my SOAP request -

```
 "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"+ 
  "xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"+ 
  "xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org"+
  "/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soap="http://soap.amazon.com">"+
  "<soapenv:Header/>"+
  "<soapenv:Body>"+
   "<soap:ActorSearchRequest soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org"+
      "/soap/encoding/">"+
      "<ActorSearchRequest xsi:type="soap:ActorRequest" xs:type="type:ActorRequest"+ 
         "xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2000/XMLSchema-instance">"+
         "<actor xsi:type="xsd:string" xs:type="type:string">abc</actor>"+
         "<page xsi:type="xsd:string" xs:type="type:string">1</page>"+
         "<mode xsi:type="xsd:string" xs:type="type:string">a</mode>"+
         "<tag xsi:type="xsd:string" xs:type="type:string">a</tag>"+
         "<type xsi:type="xsd:string" xs:type="type:string">a</type>"+
         "<devtag xsi:type="xsd:string" xs:type="type:string">a</devtag>"+            
      "</ActorSearchRequest>"+
      "</soap:ActorSearchRequest>"+
     "</soapenv:Body>"+
    "</soapenv:Envelope>";
```

Updated function -

```
function temperatureConvertor(celsiusTemp) {
    var request = '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soap="http://soap.amazon.com">'+
           '<soapenv:Header/>'+
           '<soapenv:Body>'+
              '<soap:ActorSearchRequest soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">'+
                 '<ActorSearchRequest xsi:type="soap:ActorRequest" xs:type="type:ActorRequest" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2000/XMLSchema-instance">'+
                    '<actor xsi:type="xsd:string" xs:type="type:string">abc</actor>'+
                    '<page xsi:type="xsd:string" xs:type="type:string">1</page>'+
                    '<mode xsi:type="xsd:string" xs:type="type:string">a</mode>'+
                    '<tag xsi:type="xsd:string" xs:type="type:string">a</tag>'+
                    '<type xsi:type="xsd:string" xs:type="type:string">a</type>'+
                    '<devtag xsi:type="xsd:string" xs:type="type:string">a</devtag>'+            
                 '</ActorSearchRequest>'+
              '</soap:ActorSearchRequest>'+
           '</soapenv:Body>'+
        '</soapenv:Envelope>';              
    var input = {
        method : 'post',
        returnedContentType : 'plain',
        path : '/schemas2/AmazonWebServices.wsdl',
        body: {
            content: request.toString(),
            contentType: 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'
        }
    };              
    var result = WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);               
    return result.Envelope.Body;
}
```

Updated adapter.xml

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
        <wl:adapter xmlns:wl="http://www.worklight.com/integration" xmlns:http="http://www.worklight.com/integration/http" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" name="SOAPAdapter">

            <displayName>SOAPAdapter</displayName>
            <description>SOAPAdapter</description>
            <connectivity>
                <connectionPolicy xsi:type="http:HTTPConnectionPolicyType">
                    <protocol>http</protocol>
                    <domain>soap.amazon.com</domain>
                    <port></port>           
                </connectionPolicy>
                <loadConstraints maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode="2"/>
            </connectivity>

            <procedure name="temperatureConvertor"/>

        </wl:adapter>
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of creating the SOAP request as a string you should create it as a XML literal (E4X).

Meaning, instead of `var request = "<mytag>" +  myJSVar + "</mytag>";` you should do `var request = <mytag> {myJSVar} </mytag>`;

See slides 5 and 6 in [Using HTTP adapters with SOAP Services](ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v505/Module_05_3_-_Using_HTTP_Adapters_with_SOAP_Services.pdf) for examples

Comment: Thanks a lot Aviram for a quick response, but the issue is not with the quotes. I have used the string format for a simple soap request - soap:Envelop and it works fine. Here the issue is with the soapenv element. Some how it is not being parsed properly.

Comment: You are using double quotes in the attributes without escaping them, I believe the created string is not what you expect. Either try my suggestion or escape those quotes. Also, log the string you created and see if it looks like you wanted.